# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key.) (Netlify)

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, netlify

The problem is about netlify deployment.

I am pretty sure all api key value in firebase - config works perfectly, and it works so far so good in local development environment.

The problem shows up after deployment to netlify. What may go wrong and how I could fix it?

Comment: Have you tried logging (`console.log(process.env.API_KEY)`) the API key when you deploy to netlify? Check if it is valid or undefined

Comment: it's undefined. Please advise me what mistake I have made. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and explain the steps the you followed and how you added env variables with Netlify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how's the problem incurred. Yet, I took recommendation from netlify forum to store my env variable in its build > environment variable section. The problem is resolved.

Thank you all for your attention!